# What would happen to the infinite tsukoyomi when the moon was not in the sky anymore?

Tags: naruto

Madara cast the infinite tsukoyomi with the help of the moon, when the light from the moon fell on someone, they would be cast into a genjutsu. But wouldn't that mean that the effect would wear off once the sun rose and the moon was not in the sky anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual jutsu only lasted for a few minutes; if it did not, Naruto, Sasuke, Kakashi and Sakura would have been affected when they left the cover of Sasuke's Susano. The effects of the jutsu do not end when the jutsu ends.

Comment: Oh yeah now I remember, they all came outside the susano but were unaffected!